# HighMaps grouped Hover

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

**Goal:** In the demo below, if you hover over the top right states, you will see they are all named "Intermountain". I need them all to highlight on hover, the Documentation does not really provide detail on how to do this.

I tried using the

```
             states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                },
```

but it does not do what I need.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/TUy7x/781/

```
$(function () {

    // Initiate the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('Map', {

        series: [{
            "type": "map",

            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            },
                "data": //more than highchart character limits
    });
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the downvote with no comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch mouseOver / mouseOut and then find all points with the same name.

```
series:{
            point:{
                events:{
                    mouseOver:function(){

                        var series = this.series,
                            name = this.name;

                        $.each(series.data, function(i, data){
                            if(data.name === name) {
                                data.setState('hover');
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    mouseOut:function(){
                        var series = this.series,
                            name = this.name;

                        $.each(series.data, function(i, data){
                            if(data.name === name) {
                                data.setState('');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TUy7x/782/

Comment: Great, I think there is a bug though. If you mouse over one and then go over another one with the same name, the initial one will no longer be highlighted.